# Dropdown Button Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to make a dropdown button and when I tried to make it, the position of dropdown list not in the center.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Dropdown;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */

?>
<div class="site-index">

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Selamat Datang!</h1>
        <p class="lead-lg-5">
            Aplikasi ini ditujukan untuk menampilkan <br>
            data-data dan statistik mahasiswa program Pascasarjana Universitas
        </p>
            <div class="col-md-12 school-options-dropdown text-center">
            <div class="dropdown btn-group"> <div class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Pilih Tahun Periode<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <?php
                        echo Dropdown::widget([
                        'items' => [
                                    ['label' => 'Periode 2001-2005', 'url' => "index.php?r=site%2Findexumum"],
                                    ['label' => 'Periode 2006-2010', 'url' => '#'],
                                    ['label' => 'Periode 2011-2015', 'url' => '#'],

                                    ],
                        ]);
                    ?>
                    </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

What may I do to solve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625734/why-my-dropdown-list-cant-be-position-in-center

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my dropdown list can't be position in center?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625734/why-my-dropdown-list-cant-be-position-in-center)